# Different MongoDB Connection String URI formats

Tags: mongodb

I am comparing the Connection String in our codebase, against the one used in Studio 3T.

The Connection String in our codebase:

```
mongodb://username:password@host/targetDbName?ssl=true
```

The Connection String in Studio 3T:

```
mongodb://username:password@host/?ssl=true&authSource=targetDbName
```

Is the Connection String in our codebase correct? Or does it have to be rewritten to include `?authSource=...`?

Because at the start of the [Connection String URI Format](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/#connection-string-uri-format) documentation, it's specified the Connection String has the form

```
mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,...hostN[:portN]][/[defaultauthdb][?options]]
```

**Does `defaultauthdb` correspond to `authSource`? Or are these 2 different things?**

I thought this is conflicting information, or is it true that both Connection String formats (codebase & Studio3T) can work to establish the connection?

I am not able to try another Connection String for our codebase as it is already on our dev server. I am not able to recreate the settings & environment locally.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit thank you! that means the Connection String in our codebase is correct. I tested said Connection String by importing it into Studio 3T & I was able to connect to the MongoDB database